# getting back error cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, undefined, render

I am trying to render images via api calls. I have 2 react components and i belive I am fairly close to getting images to render but in my artist.jsx i get back undefined errors and cannot figure out why. Here is the code for both components.

App component:

```
  artistOnClick(e) {
    let artist = e.target.innerHTML;
    this.getSubsequentCollabs(artist);
  }

  render() {
    const img_url = this.state.selectedArtist.img_url;
    const { artistCounts } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type='text' name="searchInput" className="searchInput" placeholder="Search Artist" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="submit" className="button" />
        </form>
        <img alt="" className="artist-img" src={this.state.selectedArtist.img_url} />
        <div id="collabs">
          {
              Object.keys(artistCounts).map((artist) => {
                return (
                  <Artist
                    name={artist}
                    image={img_url}
                    artistOnClick={this.artistOnClick}
                  />
                )
              })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Artist component:

```
const propTypes = {
  artistOnClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const artistOnClick = this.artistOnClick;
const img_url = this.props.img_url;


export default class Artist extends React.Component ({name, img_url}) {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleArtistImg = this.handleArtistImg.bind(this);
  }



  handleArtistImg(id) {
    request.get(`api`)
    .then((response) => {
      const artist = response.body.artists.items[0].images[0].url;
      let img_url = artist.images[0].url;
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={artistOnClick}>
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <div onClick={this.handleArtistImg}>
          <img src={img_url} />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div onClick={this.handleArtistImg}></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide full of both file codes.

Comment: anyway to send this thru private?

Comment: Hmm I have no idea about how to do that. Do you have the code on github ?

Comment: I am on it. Will create a pull request there.

Comment: if possible, no pull requests

Comment: Ok. I ll create an issue then.

Comment: skype frknrhn if possible

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are getting `this.state.selectedArtist.img_url` from a server via an API call? React tries to render the component before the response comes back, so `img_url` is undefined. You need to either set a default value or integrate a conditional statement for this.

```
<img alt="" className="artist-img" src={this.state.selectedArtist ? this.state.selectedArtist.img_url : '/fallback.png'} />
```

Also, in your Artist component you are defining a `let` inside `handleArtistImg()`, which means it's not possible to access it outside that method. The `const img_url = this.props.img_url;` and `const artistOnClick = this.artistOnClick;` is undefined because you tried to access `this` outside the React component. Put that in the `constructor` or use `state` for this.